# First Order Logic prove there exists a Model that has an infinite member

Tags: logic, model-theory, first-order-logic

I'm doing some extra self-exercises on first order logic (I'm taking the course through open university) and I've come across this question:

> Let there be a language $L = \{ +, \cdot, 0, 1, < \}\cup \{ c_{n} | n\in \mathbb{N}\}$ and $N$ a structure such that $|N| = \mathbb{N}$
>   whereby $c^N_{n} = n$  and all the rest of the language is interpreted
>   as the standard symbols in $\mathbb{N}$ ($+$ is addition, $\cdot$ is
>   multiplication etc.). Let us denote $T = Th(N)$
>
> For every model M of T we shall say that $a \in |M|$ is an infinite
>   member if it holds that $c^M_{n} < a$ for every $n\in{N}$
>
> For every model M of T we shall say that $p \in |M|$ is a prime number
>   if it holds that $c^M_1 < p$ and for every $a, b \in |M|$ if $p = a
> > \cdot^M b$ then $a = p$ or $a = c^M_1$
>
> Show that there exists : $M\vDash T$ such that M has an infinite
>   member.

I don't have a clue what to do here...I've sat on it for a bit but with no luck.

Any help is appreciated, Thx!

Comment: See [Non-standard model of arithmetic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-standard_model_of_arithmetic) : **From the compactness theorem**.

Comment: It's straightforward to show this using Lowenheim-Skolem theorem - you have countably many "finite" numbers, so in any uncountable model there must be an infinite one.

Comment: @user475680: The post, both in style and in formatting, is remarkably similar to [this post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1103039/first-order-logic-prove-that-the-infinitely-many-twin-primes-conjecture-is-equi).

Comment: Ah yes, I was looking for similar questions and came across that one which seems to be the same as mine so I copied the source to save some hard work :)

Comment: @bof Thank you, fixed it. The > symbol was not supposed to be there

Comment: Why did you copy the original version, rather than the edits I made (which included some improvements to the formatting)?

Comment: The title of the question may be misleading. I'd rather say: "Prove that there exists a first-order model of arithmetic with an infinite number."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT:** This is a classical use of the compactness theorem. Add an additional constant symbol $c$ and the axioms $c_n<c$ for each $n\in\Bbb N$. Now use the fact that the augmented theory is finitely satisfiable to conclude that it has a model, and it is a model of $T$.

Comment: Ah yes thank you, That was what I was missing - adding another constant and using compactness..I now have an idea what I am supposed to do, thank you!